# Clickonce app publishing using visual studio online

Tags: tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, azure-devops

I am trying to clickonce-publish a client app compiled using the scriptable build system available on Visual Studio Online. It seems something new.

I was able to find some articles showing how to customize msbuild and add parameters to make it work on local TFS:

http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.pt/2014/05/continuous-integration-with-tfs-and.html?showComment=1441022327672 and
http://www.dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2011/04/29/clickonce-publish-and-deploy-from-team-foundation-server-2010/

But in Visual Studio Online there are some different things. I see there are some "build steps" I can set that include package/deploy scripts. Can I use them for clickonce?

If setting clickonce publish during msbuild is the way to go, how to set parameters on the "visual studio build" script?

I don't know how to specify the "publish" option on msbuild script ui nor how to specify necessary parameters.

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Just as described in the blogs you posted, you need to customize build process template to be able to publish clickonce app. Here is another link which is useful for you, from which you can check the detailed information on how to do the customization step by step (includes information on how to add arguments, how to add /t:publish msbuild arguments) (*it is written for TFS2010, applies to VSO as well*): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/122388/TFS-Team-Build-with-ClickOnce-Applications

Comment: I confess that setting Visual Studio Online build is quite different (seems more limiting) from TFS2010 in my opinion. Note that I am not using any XAML templates or definition. I am using the web-base scriptable build system. The first challenge I have is to set p:/publish parameter only for the single clickonce prject I have in the entire solution. As msbuild is called once and the parameters are global, I am not sure what to do.